# Как записать время через : .Время C++

Tags: c++

Не могу нигде найти, как сделать,чтобы можно было вводить время через ":". К примеру, 09:45. Чтобы потом можно было сравнивать Разные значения времени. Например, чтобы потом можно было различать 09:20 и 09:30.

Comment: Так записывать время или вводить время? И в чем проблема считать сначала часы, потом пропустить разделитель и считать минуты сохранив результат в стандартных единицах из `<chrono>`?

Comment: Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы это время было в одной переменной?

Comment: У меня есть пример из паскаля. Хотелось бы такой же на c++ . вот код time1:=60*((ord(c)-ord('0'))*10+ ord(c1)-ord('0'));

Comment: Это очень странный Паскалевский пример ..

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, вам нужно это:

```
#include <chrono>

void foo(){
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    constexpr auto t1 = 2h + 30min + 15s;
    constexpr auto t2 = t1 - 15s;

    static_assert(t1 > t2);
    static_assert(t2 == 2h + 30min);

    constexpr auto h1 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::hours>(t1); // Округляем до часа
    constexpr auto m1 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(t1 - h1); // Остаток округряем до минут
    constexpr auto s1 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(t1 - (h1 + m1));// Остаток округряем до секунд

    constexpr int simple_seconds = s1.count();
    static_assert(simple_seconds == 15);
}
```